# Can't solve "List index out of range" error while using arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, index-error

I'm attempting to write a "cash box" style password breaker that spins dials, each dial has every character on it, until the answer is found. I'm quite new to Python (And coding in general), but with a lot of help I was able to do it with numbers and letter (capitalized and decapitalized)

Now I'm trying to build it so it only checks for numbers and decapitalized letters, not capital letters. Here is what I got:

```
def method_2(num_pass_wheels):
    result = False
    still_searching = True
    print()
    print("Using method 2 and searching with " + str(num_pass_wheels) + " characters.")
    wheel = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"
# set all of the wheels to the first position
    pass_wheel_array = array('i', [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

    while still_searching:
        ourguess_pass = ""
        for i in range(0, num_pass_wheels):  # once for each wheel
            if pass_wheel_array[i] > 0:
                ourguess_pass = wheel[pass_wheel_array[i]] + 
    ourguess_pass
        print ("trying [" + ourguess_pass + "]")
        if (check_pass(which_password, ourguess_pass)):
            print ("Success! Password  " + str(which_password) + " is " + ourguess_pass)
            still_searching = False   # we can stop now - we found it!
            result = True

 # spin the rightmost wheel and if it changes, spin the next one over and so on
        carry = 1
        for i in range(0, num_pass_wheels):  # once for each wheel
            pass_wheel_array[i] = pass_wheel_array[i] + carry
            carry = 0
            if pass_wheel_array[i] > 62:
                pass_wheel_array[i] = 1
                carry = 1
                if i == (num_pass_wheels - 1):
                    still_searching = False

    return result
```

The error message points to:

```
line 341, in <module>
    foundit = method_2(8)

line 188, in method_2
    ourguess_pass = wheel[pass_wheel_array[i]] + ourguess_pass
```

And throws the error:

```
IndexError: string index out of range
```

I know it has something to do with me removing the capital letters from "wheel" but I don't know how to go about fixing it. Any help?

Comment: Is `len(num_pass_wheels)` the same as `len(pass_wheel_array)`?  Print both of those lengths and `i` and I guess `len(wheel)` and `pass_wheel_array[i]`,  just before the offending statement - that should help you figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *hard coded* a length check limit here:

```
        if pass_wheel_array[i] > 62: <-----
            pass_wheel_array[i] = 1
            carry = 1
```

`wheel` only has only has 36 items in the version you posted.   Instead of using `62` use `len(wheel)`.

But since array indices are zero based, you might want to change it to

```
if pass_wheel_array[i] > len(wheel) - 1:
#or
if pass_wheel_array[i] == len(wheel):
```

Comment: Yup, that fixed it. Really dumb mistake there, completely forgot about coding that in. Thanks!